# three.js distortion, color replacement on glb (gltf) models. Blue changes to green, and yellow changes to orange

Tags: three.js, shader, textures, gltf

Distortion, color replacement on glb (gltf) models. Blue changes to green, and yellow changes to orange.
`v106 three.js`
`v97 GLTFLoader.js`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please check [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. How to change colors? How to prevent colors changing? Please include more details, and any code or models needed to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're using an environment map in your preview in blender. That env map has a dominant color that will affect the coloring of your model. To compare these references, you want to make sure you're using the same envmap in both blender and webgl. If you are only using lights in your threejs scene, you'll want to make sure they are colored to match.

Another thing that can affect the coloring is the gamma output settings in your THREE.Renderer, and textures.

You can go through a lot of heroics to get the outputs of both renderers to match. Read this: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/whats-this-about-gammafactor/4264

If you just want a quicker fix.. tweak your lighting/envmaps, or tweak the colors/intensity of the lights you have set up in your threejs scene.

If this behavior is something that has changed between versions of THREE.. it may be something to file a bug report on.

There are now gamma related settings on both the threejs renderer and textures.

If this isn't enough info, let me know and I may know someone else who can help set you straight :) Hi Don!

Answer (score 0):

Old question but for the record what caused it for me was the vertex colors under Object Data Properties:

[image]

Deleting the `Col` fixed the texture colors.